# Facebook Permissions error

Tags: facebook

I'm writing an app which is able to invite one's friends on facebook.

When an event is created by me, I am possible to invite my friends, BUT nobody else can do this. And when someone else creates an event it's the same of course, but that time he is possible to invite and I'm not.

The error I get is 'Permissions error' (200).

Anybody has solution for this problem? (I'm using event.invite)

Comment: How about 1)showing some code, 2)listing the permissions you are asking for, 3)when exactly you are getting the error?

Comment: I'm asking for create_event, as needed, and I guess I'm getting the error when the event is not owned by the person who wants to invite his/her friends.

Comment: still you have to show us some code. What Language? Also I thought no one but the event creator can send invites? your comments doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that you'll get a 200 error if you try and add the access tokens UID to the invitees list (yourself basically)... Took this into the graph explorer and kept trying my command, removing one UID at a time, and once I locked onto the offending UID the rest went through fine.

May also be trying to add anyone who is already invited... but I didn't get that much.